# JMDNS works on simulator but not on device

Tags: android, jmdns

I am attempting to use JMDNS to resolve a local network host's IP address. It works fine on simulator but not on phone. Anybody has any idea what the reason may be?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes do you own an HTC device by any chance?  There is a known WIFI bug that prevent UDP mutlicast DNS packets from being received.

I am the author of the ZeroConf Browser app on the Android Market and some HTC users report the exact same thing.  App works on their Motorola Xoom but not on their HTC Desire etc.

You can read more about it here:

http://code.google.com/p/tunesremote-plus/issues/detail?id=1